# How to update exsiting json file

Tags: android

I need to save json file in sdcard.I have the URL for json file.If there is any update in the json file ,i need to update the saved file.How to update the existing json file ?

Comment: You've said what you need. What have you actually tried?

Comment: i tried with ByteArrayOutputStream ,but its overrides the existing file and writes a new one.

Comment: first get the json data from file stored in sd card..append the latest data to JSONObject and then save it back to SD Card..what say ?

Comment: problem is that we can't confirm that updates add to the end of file as it contains several sections.Sometimes updates are added to the mid of the json file.